# Generic type serialization with two similarly named generic arguments

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I would like to be able to serialize a generic type against several different entities using the C# XmlSerializer. For example i want to serialize:

```
GenericThing<MyApp.A> and GenericThing<MyApp.B>
```

This all works well until i have something like the following:

```
GenericThing<MyApp.A.Entity> and GenericThing<MyApp.B.Entity>
```

Because these two classes have the same name the serializer cant differentiate between the two entities and attempts to serialize both to `GenericThingOfEnitity`.

Is there a way of decorating `GenericThing` so that it is more specific about its generic argument during serialization (ie serializes to `GenericThingOfMyApp.B.Enitity` or similar)? I unfortunately don't have control over either `MyApp.A` or `MyApp.B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify different XML namespaces, e.g.:

```
var entityA = new GenericThing<MyApp.Entity>();
var entityB = new GenericThing<MyAppB.Entity>();
var serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(entityA.GetType(), "aaa");
var serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(entityB.GetType(), "bbb");
```

Comment: Can i do this at the generic type level?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: IE can i decorate my GenericThing class with an attribute that will sort out the namespacing for the different possible child classes? (BTW it wasn't me down voting)

Comment: @LukeMcGregor, Probably not. But you can implement 2 different `GenericThing` classes and mark them with `XmlRootAttribute` specifying different namespaces.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor, ... and you always can implement `IXmlSerializable`.